# asp:Hyperlink Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, asp.net, object, hyperlink, .net-1.1

For all of my hyperlinks I keep getting this error and not really sure why.

I have looked at all of the other questions that are similar but nothing really has helped.

Here is the format of the hyperlinks that keep throwing this error.

```
<asp:HyperLink id="BuyLink" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# Application["ApplicationPath"].ToString() + "/StoreModules/AddToCart.aspx?PID=" + DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"ProductID").ToString() %>' ImageUrl='<%# Application["CommonImages"] + "buy_btn.gif" %>' />
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's wrong with setting the `NavigateUrl` and `ImageUrl` properties in the code behind? I suspect this is where the issue is. It would be a lot easier to debug if they were set in code

Comment: The only reason I had not done it in the code behind was because this is an .net 1.1 site that I am upgrading to .net 4.0 and was just trying to preserve the code. Doing it in the code behind was my last resort haha Also these hyperlinks are in asp:datagrids @DGibbs

Comment: I'd move that inline code to the code behind personally, it _may_ not be the issue but if you're upgrading to 4.0 i see no reason not to do this at the same time. Think of the poor soul that has to maintain it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's acceptable to you to hard code the ImageUrl property, then this should work. Notice the ~/ at the start of the paths to get the app root folder:

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="BuyLink" runat="server" 
    NavigateUrl='<%# "~/StoreModules/AddToCart.aspx?PID=" + DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ProductID").ToString() %>' 
    ImageUrl="~/CommonImagesFolder/buy_btn.gif" />
```

Comment: this works but also going around it in the server side works as well! Thanks